# Writing pandas df to a (csv) file in a complicated format

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

I am dealing with a pandas dataFrame which has 6 columns, I want to write those columns to a file, preferably in .txt format(But I am using df.to_csv method, and not using .csv extension, so it appears to be a text file).
Following is the example df

```
      a    b    c    d    e    f
    0 1    6    34   99   2    5
    1 9    8    89   56   33   77
    2 4    55   45   87   54   34
```

When I write this dataframe to the file, following is what I expect:

```
    1  6  34
    99 2  5
    9  8  89
    56 33 77
    4  55 45
    87 54 34
```

As we can see, the first three and last three values of a row should be in different lines in the file for all the rows of the df; without header and and index.

Following is the simple code which I used to eliminate the header and index, but I am clue less how to achieve rest of the criteria. I cannot format the output file manually, because its a huge dataframe with thousands of rows. Also once I have written the data for one df, I will have to append data from another df (same in structure) which is equally large.

```
with open('output', 'a+') as f:
     df.to_csv(f, header = False, index = False, sep = " ")
```

Or rather I should completely go for a different approach, like defining a function for the task?

Comment: This answer would be helpful for your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/a/27514161/4399016

Answer (score 1):

First, change flat column names to two-level hierarchical names: prepare new names as a list of tuples and create a new index from the list.

```
new_columns = [(a,b) for b in (0,1) for a in df.columns[:len(df.columns)/2]]
#[('a', 0), ('b', 0), ('c', 0), ('a', 1), ('b', 1), ('c', 1)]
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(new_columns)
#df
#   a   b   c   a   b   c
#   0   0   0   1   1   1
#0  1   6  34  99   2   5
#1  9   8  89  56  33  77
#2  4  55  45  87  54  34
```

Note how each column has two names, and the first names are repeated. Now, stack the dataframe: convert the second column name into a row name:

```
tall = df.stack()
#      a   b   c
#0 0   1   6  34
#  1  99   2   5
#1 0   9   8  89
#  1  56  33  77
#2 0   4  55  45
#  1  87  54  34
```

And the tall dataframe is ready to go to file:

```
tall.to_csv(filename, header=False, index=False, sep=' ')
#1  6   34
#99 2   5
#9  8   89
#56 33  77
#4  55  45
#87 54  34
```

Comment: i wonder if the OP would prefer the dataframe as a fixed width file, as `np.savetxt('output.txt', tall.values, fmt='%d')`?

Comment: Hi, I tried the code u suggested but I am getting a TypeError after executing the first part (before stacking). The exact error is 'TypeError: cannot perform __truediv__ with this index type: <class 'pandas.indexes.base.Index'

Comment: Sorry,  put a closing parenthesis in a wrong place.